# Separate Label and Input

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button, label

I have a `label` that contains a `Input` `Radio` with a background image.
As you can see here [image]

I need the "Ja" and "Nej" to be like 5-10pix to the left, but I just can't seem to find a solution.
Can someone help me here ?

HTML:

```
<label id="labelradio1" for="Radio1">Ja
<input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="yes"></label>
<label id="labelradio2" for="Radio2">Nej
<input id="Radio2" type="radio" value="no"></label>
```

CSS:

```
#txtradiocall input[type='radio']{
    position:absolute;
    margin: -99999px;
}


#txtradiocall label{
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 4px;

}

#txtradiocall #labelradio1 {
    background: url('http://www.xxxx.com/images/images/thumb_up_green-v2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    height: 22px;
}

#txtradiocall #labelradio2 {
    background: url('http://www.xxxx.com/images/images/thumb_down-red-v2.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    height: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
#txtradiocall #labelradio1 {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/35/22');
}
#txtradiocall #labelradio2 {
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/35/22');
}

#txtradiocall label {
    padding: 0 40px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 35px;
    height: 22px;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SY3ry/).

The above specifies the `background-image` property, rather than the shorthand, because with the shorthand the `id`-based selectors overrides the later declarations for `background-repeat` and `background-position` (since the shorthand defines all properties, `-color`, `-repeat` and `-position`).

Also, specify all shared properties in one place, which makes it easier to keep properties consistent and more easily maintainable.

Comment: [placekitten](http://placekitten.com/) rocks..! Though I'm more of a dog-person, myself; but since (last I checked) placepuppies doesn't exist, I'll happily apply kittens to any pictorial problem. =D